# repo tool how to update a private branch (working with gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab, repo

I am working with repo tool for a long time, I used to work with gerrit and now switched into gitlab.

I used to have this flow of:

1. repo init (manifest etc...)
2. repo sync ...
3. create a new commit
4. code review in gerrit
5. repo sync -> in order to update to lastest
6. fix the commit review and push the amended commit
7. repo sync and back to 3-6

When working with gitlab you create a new branch and a new MR for each commit (of many commits... whatever you want)
so the basically I am asking for the way to repo sync my current branch with latest master

1. repo init (manifest etc...)
2. repo sync ...
3. create a new commit -> new branch main/giladdar/my_kickass_fix (for example)
4. code review in gitlab
5. how do I get the latest master into my branch?

Can you please describe the best practice?

Comment: It's normally done by pulling (merge or rebase).... much the same way you did using gerrit (at least, from `git`'s point of view).

Comment: Gitlab's Merge Request is basically the same thing with Gerrit's Pending Change. The steps related with the local repository should be the same. In your Gerrit flow, I don't think Step 5 is necessary. `repo sync` does not fetch a pending change unless you specify its ref in the manifest and run `repo init` again. `repo sync` simply tries to update to the latest branch or the specified commit depending on the value of `revision` in the manifest. In both cases, your local commit could be "lost" (by `repo sync -d`) or nothing happens (by `repo sync` without `-d`).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a branch or a fork for MR.
2. You should not name your branch **main/giladdar/my_kickass_fix** but rather **giladdar/my_kickass_fix** (or better, use Jira integration and set the branch name to refer to the task).
3. GitLab will not let you complete the MR if your branch is not in sync with the **main** (or whatever branch you want to merge into). You have to rebase your branch to be in sync with latest state of the target branch (**main**), and GitLab won't do it for you (but see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29406).
4. It's your responsibility to update your branch, and make sure that it doesn't break after that. The MR cannot be approved while its branch is behind the target branch.
5. If your repo is set up for that, you can request for the MR to be
   fulfilled automatically when the Pipeline succeeds:    https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html.